# Type comparison in assembly

Tags: assembly, types, x86, masm, dosbox

I am currently in an assembly class for school so I am still a novice.

Is there a typeid command in assembly or a way to compare to types together? Ideally similar to this in C++

```
typeid(var) != typeid(int)
```

There is nothing in the book we are using that I have found so far. Our professor only went over basic jmp/cmp commands, there was nothing to compare type in what we have learned.

Comment: Generally, no. However [masm does seem to have a TYPE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-type). Not sure whether that works for your use case.

Comment: Types are a compile-time thing in C++.  In MASM, if there's any support at all, it would be with [`if` assemble-time directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/if-masm?view=msvc-160) equivalent to C++ `#if`, because there's no equivalent of C++'s optimizer that can turn `cmp/jcc` into dead code removal for conditions that are always true.  (`if` is different from the `.if` / `.while` "high level assembly" crap that assemble into cmp/jcc to compare registers.)